# WordPress: Get all tags from custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to get all the tags that are within my custom post type "resource".

The problem is that I'm outside of the loop and struggling to find a way to get the functionality to work with the custom post type.

I have the category setup also as "resource_category"

My current code is:

```
$tax = 'post_tag';
$terms = get_terms( $tax );
$count = count( $terms );

if ( $count > 0 ): ?>
    <div class="post-tags">
    <?php
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, $tax );
        echo '<a href="' . $term_link . '" class="tax-filter" title="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a> ';
    } ?>
    </div>
<?php endif;
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: chec out these answers http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104011/show-tags-of-custom-post-type-only?answertab=votes#tab-top https://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-all-tags-used-in-custom-post-type

Answer (score 8):

Tags are also WordPress taxonomy. So, you can get all the tags as like you get all terms
[Read More](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/categories-tags-custom-taxonomies/)

```
$tags = get_terms([
          'taxonomy'  => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_TAXONOMY',
          'hide_empty'    => false
        ]);
var_dump($tags);
```

You can also copy custom post taxonomy from Tags page URL.

http://localhost/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TAG_TAXONOMY_NAME&post_type=custom-post-type

Answer (score 7):

you are asking for the tags right, because the answer from 2015 is listing categories not tags

```
$args = array(
        'type' => get_post_type(),
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order' => 'ASC'
);
$tags = get_tags($args);

foreach($tags as $tag) { 
    var_dump($tag->name);
}
```

Comment: `type` isn't listed in the WordPress codex. Do you have a link to where you're getting this from? I'm looking at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/